# Insert data into table when i am using trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

Here is a trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckApplyId]
ON [dbo].[AppliedStudent_event] INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    DECLARE @studentId INT
    DECLARE @compReq_Id INT
    BEGIN
        SELECT @studentId = studentId
        FROM   INSERTED

        SELECT @compReq_Id = compReq_Id
        FROM   INSERTED

        IF EXISTS(SELECT StudentId,
                         compreq_id
                  FROM   AppliedStudent_event
                  WHERE  StudentId = @studentId
                         AND compreq_id = @compReq_Id)
        BEGIN
            ROLLBACK
            PRINT 'User Already Applied'
        END
    END
```

When in insert a data into a table using command:

```
INSERT INTO AppliedStudent_event (StudentId, compreq_id)
VALUES (3026, 1)
```

Message is:

```
(1 row(s) affected)
```

But when I execute a sql command no data is inserted in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell why are you using trigger because you use only assign the variable  @studentId and @compReq_Id from inserted table.

Answer (score 0):

That's a broken trigger because [`inserted`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) can contain *multiple* (or *no*) rows - so a statement like `SELECT @ScalarVariable = column from inserted` is always wrong.

And it's unnecessary since you can just place a UNIQUE constraint on the `StudentId` and `compreq_id` columns:

```
ALTER TABLE AppliedStudent_event
ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_Student_Events
    UNIQUE (StudentId,compreq_id)
```

And it's further broken because you've specified it as an instead of trigger - that says that **your** code is going to be responsible for the actual insert - but your code doesn't actually do that. That's why no data ends up in the table.

---

If you insist on doing it as a trigger, it's actually tricky to get everything correct (that's why I'd really recommend the `UNIQUE` constraint). It'll end up being something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[CheckApplyId]
ON [dbo].[AppliedStudent_event] INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    IF EXISTS(select
                 StudentId,compreq_id,COUNT(*)
              from inserted
              group by StudentId,compreq_id
              HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    OR EXISTS (select *
               from inserted i
                inner join
                  AppliedStudent_event e
                   on
                     i.StudentId = e.StudentId and
                     i.compreq_id = e.compreq_id)
    BEGIN
         ROLLBACK
         PRINT 'User Already Applied'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
         INSERT INTO AppliedStudent_event(StudentId,compreq_id /* Other columns? */)
         SELECT StudentId,compreq_id /* And again, other columns */
         FROM inserted
    END
```